# Linear combinations and GCD

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

> Find a solution for the equation $36x + 54y = 15$.

I know the GCD is $18$ linear combination of $18$ but I'm asked to find the linear combination of $15$ with same numbers.

Comment: It's not possible.

Comment: Hint: the left hand side is an even number.

Comment: You don't explicitly say that you want _integer_ solutions or that this is a Diophantine equation.  There are rational solutions to the equation.